# How can I get a User's field in Account Team Member?

Tags: user, account-teams

I have a field in "Account Team Member" called "MemberEnrollment__c" that have to get the value of "Enrollment__c" (field in "User")

How can I do it? I've tried by formula but I doesn't work...

Comment: What did you try? What error or behavior did you see? Please [edit] to show us the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Reed said please edit your question to show us the problem, your formula field and what you have tried to do. It is important to add these items to this forum so that other people can see these posts and learn from them as well. Not just for you to get an answer to your problem. I will proceed to answer the question based on my understanding, but PLEASE Edit the question to provide more details.

In addition please thoroughly search this forum and Salesforce documentation and threads for an answer before posting a duplicate question. Chances are your question has already been answered..

It sounds like based on your description you enabled Account Teams in your org and you want to create a formula field on the Account Team Member object that displays a custom field on the parent user record `Enrollment__c`

Do reference parent fields in Apex or a formula field you add __r for custom lookup fields or if it is a standard lookup field you use the api name on the field.

For example if I wanted to create a formula field on Contact that displays the parent Account Name, I would use the following formula

```
Account.Name
```

For your use case it is the same. The AccountTeamMember has a lookup field called `User`.

[image: Account Team Member User Field]

to access any fields on the [parent] user object you can create a custom formula(Text) field on the AccountTeamMember use the following formula:

```
User.FirstName
```

or in your case:

```
User.Enrollment__c
```

if Enrollment__c is a picklist field you will need to use the TEXT() function to properly access the value.

You can also go up multiple levels using [Cross-Object formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_cross_object.htm&type=0) (I believe 10 )

i.e,

```
Contact.Account.CustomLookupField1__r.CustomLookupField2__r.Name
```